# run a script after a binary was called

Tags: networking, network-interface, networkmanager, vpn, monitoring

I would like to modify **iptables** after *VPN connection*. What is the best approach to achieve that ?

I already tried through **systemd** with a custom unit in **NetworkManager** *dispatcher.d* directory but it seems to only work at boot, not if *VPN* is stopped and restarted - if I wrote it right :

```
[Unit]
Description=iptables setup
Requires=nordvpnd.service
After=nordvpn.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/setup_iptables.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I could monitor ***tun0***, if up and configured, parsing the result of :

```
ip address ls dev tun0
```

but that would mean delay between update. Ex. test every 5 sec. could mean at least 4 sec. when iptables is not configured as it should.

My last idea would be to run setup_iptables.sh every time **/usr/bin/nordvpn** is called, but how to achieve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `/usr/bin/nordvpn` return immediately after it is called or does it return after completing the VPN connection?

In the latter case, just rename `/usr/bin/nordvpn` to `/usr/bin/nordvpn.original` and create a script `/usr/bin/nordvpn` that first calls `/usr/bin/nordvpn.original` and then `/usr/local/bin/setup_iptables.sh` (this is called a "wrapper script").

If `/usr/bin/nordvpn` returns immediately, it's harder, because you need in your wrapper script to somehow check if VPN connection has been established (maybe by pinging something particular?) and if yes, then run `/usr/local/bin/setup_iptables.sh`.

Comment: Very nice : many thanks !